# C# add function or variable method to string variable

Tags: c#, overriding

I want to be able to add my own functions and variables to the existing string variable.

Such as instead of

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(mystring) == false)
```

I do this

```
if(mystring.isEmpty == false)
```

With isEmpty's get just returning isnullorempty().
This is just one of many functions I need to add to this variable to speed things up.

note* string not String

Comment: "speed things up"? Seriously?

Comment: @BoltClock: speed up his/her typing, perhaps? :shrug:

Comment: @BoltClock What I am requesting is not limited to just the string variable, I need mutliple changes for differnt existing classes as well.

Comment: @Drake: you misunderstood.  His question was about "functions I need to speed things up".  How do you plan to speed things up by using extension methods?

Comment: Also, `string` is the same as `String`.

Comment: Speed up typing by having intellisense recommend the mthod straight from the variable instead of referencing another class and getting the function from there

Comment: @Drake: in that case, extension methods are what you want.  Even so, consider the architecture of your program.  Don't do things just so that Intellisense is 10ms faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).  But be careful not to make them act differently from normal methods.

Comment: I checked this out before asking, this doesn't show how to add variables, only functions.

Comment: @Drake: you can't add methods to specific variables (like you can in JavaScript, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Use extension method.
Create a static class and then declare static method(extension methods) on string like this

//this indicates you are extending method in string class

```
public static bool isEmpty(this string input)
{
   //your logic
}
```

All the linq queries have been implemented as extension methods

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement extension method like below :

```
public static bool isEmpty(this string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance every type with extension methods. But unfortunately you can only write methods, **properties can not be added to a type**. So `if(mystring.isEmpty == false)` of your sample is only working with a method like this `if(mystring.IsEmpty() == false)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Thats not a function, thats a property
2. You can create new extension methods for string, but there arent extension properties in C# 4
3. There is no difference between string and String
4. In the .Net World isEmpty would start with a capital letter
5. Instead of writing `if (someBool == false)` you should write `if (!someBool)`
6. I highly question any speed improvement that you hope to see here. VS has great IntelliSense features you should learn and use those.